# How to scroll down a compoenent without scrolling whole page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react element which is a chat box. Now i want to scroll to the bottom of this box. While i use scrollintoview , it scrolls to the bottom of the page and scrolls the chat aswell. I dont want to scroll the page.

```
class Preview extends Component {
  messageEndRef = React.createRef();
.........
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.messageEndRef.current) {
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  }
.........

scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.messageEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' }); 
  };
.........
```

Is there any way to just scroll preview and not the whole page?

Comment: Have you tried this? `this.messageEndRef.current.scrollTop = this.messageEndRef.current.scrollHeight`

Comment: yes i tried this , it prevents scrolling of both the chat box and the page. However i want to scroll the message box keeping the position of page same as previous